# How would I solve this integral with natural log?

Tags: calculus

If y= $\displaystyle \int \ln \left(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)$ , then dy/dx is :

I have spent quite a bit of time trying to figure out how to solve this problem. I've tried it myself and have even plugged it into an online calculator. None of the answers have matched the options from the multiple choice. Thanks for the help in advance!

The options are:

a) $\dfrac{1}{x^2+1}$
b)$\dfrac{1}{\left(x\right)\left(x^2+1\right)}$
c)$\dfrac{2x^2+1}{\left(x\right)\left(x^2+1\right)}$
d)$\dfrac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2+1}}$
e)$\dfrac{1-x^2}{\left(x\right)\left(x^2+1\right)}$

Comment: What did your calculator say?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure how to plug in an integral without it having the numbers above and below the right of the integral symbol.

Comment: You are integrating w.r.t. which variable?

Comment: Is that integral sign supposed to be there?  If so, I don't think any of the answers fit (if the integral is with respect to $\text{d}x$.  If not, then use the chain rule.

Comment: Everything I have on there is what is on my paper. I found another online calculator, and it gave me very odd results that I interpreted to mean that the answer was A. I'm still confused by it.

Comment: By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, the derivative of the integral of $f(x)$ is again $f(x)$(given the derivative and integral exist). So there would be not that much to do...

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an error in the problem statement: it appears that the integral sign is not meant to be there.  If you set $y = \ln(x / \sqrt(x^2 + 1))$ --without the integral sign--then indeed $dy/dx$ is one of the choices given.

In other words, I think you're being asked to differentiate the thing on the right side of the (unintended) integral sign.

There's an online calculator here http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Online+Derivative+Calculator that may help, but you may be better off taking this on your own from here. (I am assuming you are trying to get unstuck on this problem, rather than just trying to get someone to hand you the answer.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I am indeed trying to work through the problem, especially since I will be taking the AP in a few weeks. I'm absolutely terrible at these things, but I think that I'll figure it out. Thanks again!

Comment: Considering that the problem you're having such difficulty with is apparently _wrongly_ _written_, you may be better at this than you think.